# Number of epimorphisms from free group to given group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

What is the number of epimorphisms from $F_3$ to $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_p\oplus\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^5}$, for some prime $p$?

I understand that $G$ is generated by three elements (two of order $p$ and one of order $p^5$). Let's fix those generators. Each automorphism of $G$ will map them to another generator triple.

Am I correct in my assumption that there are exactly $|Aut(G)|$ epimorphisms?

Comment: No. Mapping the generators of $F_3$ to $(1,0,1), (0,1,1), (0,0,1)$ maps the generators to three elements of order $p^5$. This cannot be obtained via an automorphism from the more obvious map $F\to G$,

Comment: I was afraid it would be so. What is the number of epis then?